# When using XElement Value, is it possible to get the non-concatenated text for a parent node?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Say you have an XElement that looks like this

```
    <name>
    TESTING
      <given>GIVENNAME2</given>
      <family>FAMILYNAME</family>
    </name>



var descend = elements.ElementAt(i).DescendantsAndSelf();
            foreach (XElement x in descend)
            {
                string g = x.Value;
            }
```

Result for name element is

```
    TESTING
      GIVENNAME2FAMILYNAME
```

When I try to get the value of individual elements, it works for children nodes like given and family, but when I try to get the text contained in the parent element, Value returns that text, plus the concatenated text of all the child nodes.   Does anyone know how to get just the text 'TESTING' as a discrete value form the parent node? And ignore the text of the child nodes?

Not only do I need to read, but I need to change the value as well, which is why I need it as a discrete value.

Comment: Text is just another child node - deal with it the same as other child nodes like `given` in you sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Nodes` method and look for nodes with a `NodeType` of `XmlNodeType.Text`.

```
var elements = XElement.Parse(@"<name>
    TESTING
      <given>GIVENNAME2</given>
      <family>FAMILYNAME</family>
    </name>");

// grab just the first text node for your specific case
// (since we know the structure of this example)
var text = elements.Nodes().OfType<XText>().First();
Console.WriteLine("Before: " + text.Value);
text.Value = "Hello, World!";
Console.WriteLine("After: " + text.Value);

// general approach to inspect all nodes
foreach (var node in elements.Nodes())
{
    switch (node.NodeType)
    {
        case XmlNodeType.Text:
            var xtext = (XText)node; // could just ToString() it
            Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", node.NodeType, xtext.Value);
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.Element:
            var xelement = (XElement)node;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1} : {2}", node.NodeType,
                xelement.Name, xelement.Value);
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine(node);
            break;
    }    
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked, but there's one side effect.  When I change the value of the text and write out the XDocument back to string, the formatting (line breaks, or indentation) between nodes is removed even though I specified XmlWriter settings Ident = true.   Just for the area of the document I modified, the rest looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This method is used to get the individual inner value of the specified element.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element">Contains the XElement to retrieve a value.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns only the inner value of the element specified.</returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// XElement.Value returns a concatenated string of all child element values. This is bad if
    /// only the inner text value of the specified element is required.
    /// </remarks>
    public static string InnerValue(this XElement element)
    {
        // get the last child node of NodeType = Text...
        var textNode = element.Nodes().OfType<XText>().LastOrDefault();

        // return the value of the text node if found
        return textNode != null ? textNode.Value : string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: Much cleaner and re-usable way is to create an extension method. The method above will return only the last text node found. 

If you have <XElement> XText1 <XElement/> XText2 </XElement> it will only return the value of XText2. 

Another alternative is to Concatenate the values all XText nodes found. This wasn't important for us, as we dictate in our XSD that all child elements must come before our text nodes.